# Simple, cross-browser way to get the WHOLE page width in JavaScript, not just the viewport width?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, width

I've seen lots of posts that talk about the getting width of the browser viewport, but what I want to find is essentially the width of the browser viewport if it were just wide enough to avoid a horizontal scrollbar.

I'm using the Prototype JS framework and have looked at various options using that and using pure JavaScript.  For example:

- `$(document.body).getWidth()` and `document.body.clientWidth` return the viewport width excluding margins.
- `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `window.innerWidth` return the viewport width including margins.

I've tried to be sneaky too: I absolutely-positioned a known-width DIV against the right-hand edge of the page (i.e. CSS `right:0`) with the intention of getting its left-edge position, but that actually gets aligned with the right-edge of the viewport.

The only thing I've found that works is to use JavaScript to scroll right until it won't scroll anymore (simply using `scrollBy(1000000, 0)` will usually be enough, but a while loop would obviously be more reliable), then get the horizontal scroll offset and add that to the viewport width.  But I don't want to scroll the window: I want to inspect it somehow!

Any suggestions appreciated, even jQuery ones as at least then I can see how jQuery does it.

---

Here's a simple example showing that `document.body.scrollWidth` doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body onload="document.getElementById('sw').innerHTML = document.body.scrollWidth">
<p><code>document.body.scrollWidth</code> = <span id="sw"></span></p>
<div style="position:absolute;left:0;bottom:0;width:1980px;background-color:#ccc;padding:10px;">This DIV is 2000px wide including padding.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of this should show that the width is 2000px, since that's the width of the widest part of the page.  It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
window.screen.width;
```

---

```
document.body.style.width = (window.screen.width - 15) + 'px';
```

`window.screen.width - 15` is enough to avoid horizontal scroll-bar. `15` is  vertical scrollbar width.

Comment: I don't think that provides what he's asking

Comment: `window` doesn't have a property named `screen` in any browser.

Comment: Thanks, but `screen.width` is the width of the screen: it's nothing to do with the size of the browser window or its content!

Comment: @Teemu Yes it is. Check  this out: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#screenview

Comment: And that link confirms what I said: it defines `screen.width` and `screen.height` as "The width and height of the screen".

Answer (score 0):

for width:

```
document.body.scrollWidth
```

for height:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

EDIT: for IE you'll have to specify `position:relative` for the body tag

Comment: Thanks, but I've also tried this one before.  In my tests it is always the same as `document.body.clientWidth` (I've not got a vertical scrollbar) which is the viewport width including margins, and is significantly less than the actual complete page width.

Comment: If that's not working you're doing something pretty strange with your markup. Can you post it, or make a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Actually, my markup couldn't be much simpler!  I'll edit the original post to give an example using `scrollWidth` since I can't seem to do it here.

Comment: I tested out your example, and for IE you'll need to specify position:relative for the body tag

Comment: Thanks, yes `position:relative` on the body tag does help in IE8+, Safari (I've got v5) and Chrome (v25) but unfortunately doesn't help in Firefox (v19), IE7 or Opera (v12).  It also has the unfortunate side-effect of messing up the page layout in the example I posted.  Still it's a step in the right direction I think.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't treat html and body like ordinary elements. In particular many browsers are really buggy with respect to how they treat scrollWidth etc. on the body element.
The only real solution is to wrap all your content in one huge div for the entire page and use that. Because the div is an ordinary element it isn't affected by the bugs that cause the weird behaviour for body and html.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't always appear to work.  If you wrap the content of the example above ("simple example showing that `document.body.scrollWidth` doesn't work") in a DIV, and get the `offsetWidth` of that DIV, you'll see it's the same as `document.body.scrollWidth`, which means the DIV is only as wide as the browser viewport (minus margins).  I think this approach would work if there were no absolutely-positioned elements.